# Logged in using Gmail account from iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an iPhone application, I implement Facebook login on my app, now users can logged in to my app using their FB account. I also want to implement Gmail login to my app, then users can logged in to my app using their Gmail account. Is it possible to implement Gmail login on iPhone app. Any API for Objective-C for Gmail login is available?

Thanks,
VKS

Comment: iFone? http://technabob.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/01/ifone_iphone.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out the link for google api for objective c client but they don't provide for the login a user from google credentials

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/